# add directory to the classpath of jetty in eclipse started with maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jetty

I need your help on how to add a custom classes/config directory to my jetty plugin in eclipse, which is started by maven. I have searched through this site and eclipse site and none of them resolved my issue.

my pom.xml of my web project in eclipse are as follows:

```
        <build>
            <finalName>rompii-webservice</finalName>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.6</source>
                        <target>1.6</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                 <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                  </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
```

my jetty-env.xml has the following:

```
<Configure class="org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <New id="esvcOracle" class="org.mortbay.jetty.plus.naming.Resource">
        <Arg>jdbc/storeDS</Arg>
        <Arg>
            <New class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource">
                <Set name="DriverType">thin</Set>
                <Set name="URL">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1540:store</Set>
                <Set name="User">store_user</Set>
                <Set name="Password">password</Set>
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </New>
</Configure>
```

What should I add to my pom or my jetty-env.xml? Thank you in advance.

Comment: you don't have any jetty maven plugin configuration or declaration in your pom, how are you running the embedded jetty server? what's the path (directory structure) of these additional classes/config directories?

Comment: Hi @A.DiMatteo, I have a jetty maven plugin and I'm currently using it. My only issue is to load the .properties into my classpath from the external directory. That's why I need to add the external directory to my jetty classpath.